# App crashes as soon as it's opened - E/FragmentManager: No view found for id

Tags: java, android

**Fragment error logcat in which the home fragment us not liking it when I try and launch the app if crashes straight away.**

```
2019-09-23 16:45:10.033 6139-6139/? E/ex.connexsocia: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000 2019-09-23 16:45:11.249 6139-6139/com.connex.connexsocial E/FragmentManager: No view found for id 0x7f080055 (com.connex.connexsocial:id/container) for fragment HomeFragment{3cd0405 (50d70a86-2cb8-4ba3-844c-f016bd5545cb) id=0x7f080055 } 2019-09-23 16:45:11.249 6139-6139/com.connex.connexsocial E/FragmentManager: Activity state: 2019-09-23 16:45:11.269 6139-6139/com.connex.connexsocial E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.connex.connexsocial, PID: 6139
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HomeFragment">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="30sp" 
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Home" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Add Fragment code.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HomeFragment">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Home" />
 </FrameLayout>

Comment: your textview has no id ... may be that is the issue

Comment: show the code that is throwing this exception.

Comment: I'll alter this, I also cannot post all my code when asking a question here. If you need to see the .java let me know.

Comment: you have to post the code. Don't post full code, show only couple lines of code which throw this exception.

Comment: This is the whole code https://docs.google.com/document/d/1zikw5aYOclB3LZSGFI6lWb3EzMhxYaZIN73Zpe6c2QE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: as I said, `Don't post full code, show only couple lines of code which throw this exception.`

Comment: I'm a noob at this, I don't know how to...I'm still learning

Comment: check the exception stacktrace, locate where it points to your code and show the code where it points to.

Comment: show your Fragment class @Erin

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1zikw5aYOclB3LZSGFI6lWb3EzMhxYaZIN73Zpe6c2QE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code there, never use off-site resources to share code. The problem is in the code where you are adding this fragment. Check it or show it.

Answer (score 0):

As I see there's no `id` set for your `TextView`. Give it an `id` like below, hope it will work.

```
<TextView
 android:id="@+id/tv_name_your_textview"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:textAlignment="center"
 android:textSize="30sp" 
 android:gravity="center"
 android:text="Home" />
```

Then call it from your fragment like:(I am doing it in kotlin)

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val containerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_restaurant_food_cart_preview, container, false)
    containerView.tv_name_your_textview.text = "Some value"
    return containerView 
}
```

Comment: this won't help, as the problem is with fragment

Comment: I have updated the answer though, you may check. Or you can share your code using pastebin

Comment: please don't ask to share code using offsite resource, it should never be done.

Comment: Also please don't try to answer the question before you are sure you understand it, and you are sure you have all the required details.

Answer (score 0):

To add a fragment to activity we can use container id in Framelayout,
but you forgot to use id in framelayout.
so add id in your framelayout.

```
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             tools:context=".HomeFragment"
            android:id="@+id/container">


    <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Home" />

</FrameLayout>
```

and add fragment like this in your activity

```
 FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.container, new HomeFragment()).commit();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment{
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup 
        container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment,container,false);
    return view;
}
```

initialize the fragment layout like this

Comment: this won't help, as the problem is with fragment